# String manipulation in Grub2

Tags: grub, script, grub2

One of the new features of Grub2 is scriptability.  At my work we're using it to great affect.  However, I recent stumbled on a terrible short coming.  There isn't any string manipulation or arithmetic support.

My exact problem: I need to mess with a PCI device before booting.  Between `setpci` and `write_dword` I can easily write the values I need to.  I get the Base address register from `setpci`, and 0x18 to it, and write the desired value to that address.

I did the math in my head while experimenting, but now I can't figure out how to get Grub2 to do the same math at boot time.

To add insult to injury, the PCI address always end in 000.  So in theory I could just replace the last two 0's with *"18"* and that would work as well.  Once again Grub2 fails me, with no string manipulation support.

Is there a way to get a substring in Grub2 script?
Is there a way to perform arithmetic in Grub2 script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want scriptability in Grub2, you need the [lua support](http://grub.enbug.org/LUASupport), which is not part of the released version. It's part of the [grub-extras](https://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/grub-extras/), and you can get the [source from the bazaar repository](http://bzr.savannah.gnu.org/r/grub-extras/lua). You'll need to rebuild Grub2 from source. I don't think there's any documentation apart from the source, though you can ask for help on the [grub-devel](http://lists.gnu.org/mailman/listinfo/grub-devel) mailing list. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

The `regexp` command can be used to do limited string manipulation.

https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/grub.html#regexp

untested example:

```
regexp --set base "(....)00" "$reg"
if [ "$base" != "" ]; then
    setpci "${base}18" ...
fi
```